# Install ursina on Windows11

Tags: python, windows, pip

the code on terminal:
pip3 install ursina

din't work.

can somebody help me installing ursina on windows 11.

i also tried :
pip install ursina

and it also didn't work.

PS: i knew
pip3 -m install ursina
does not work.

1. Open Terminal
2. Type : pip3 install ursina
3. Should install (but didn't)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Didn't work, but what did it output? Consider including output too else it would be simply not possible to guess the issue.

Comment: "It didn't work" is not useful information for us. Please include the whole traceback of the error you are getting. Without that we have no idea why it didn't work. It could be that you don't have pip installed, or that you had no access to internet so pip could download the package, or maybe you are using a diferent environment that the one where the package is installed. All this could be easily check by just posting the traceback of the error you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `python3 -m pip install ursina`?

It is generally recommended that you run pip using `python3 -m pip`.

Otherwise, the instructions on the [ursina](https://pypi.org/project/ursina/) package pypi page provides some good installation help.